# Unknown 'FBSDKCoreKit' module in Swift2 Xcode 7 beta

Tags: swift2, xcode7-beta2

I use Xcode 7 beta with Swift2 and when I import FBSDKCoreKit the error appear like this "*No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit*' ". How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, however the following has resolved mine.

1. Do copy the frameworks in the destination group as XCode 7 beta version gives a linker problem if you just give a reference by unchecking the "Copy items if needed" option.
2. In your build settings, make sure that you set the value to "Yes" for "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules". The setting can be found under "Apple LLVM 7.0 - Language - Modules".